# Parse XML in Scala via StAX

Tags: xml, scala, stax

Whats the best way to parse big XML file using Scala and StAX parser?

Format is non-recursive like

```
<items>
  <item>
      <field1>Value</field1>
      . . .
      <fieldN></fieldN>
  </item>
</items>
```

But I don't like JAVA-style:

```
val path = new URL( . . . )

val inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
val reader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(path.openStream())

var items = ??? SOME MUTABLE COLLECTION?
var currentItem = ??? NULL?

try {
  while (reader.hasNext) {
    val event = reader.nextEvent()

    if (event.isStartElement) {
      event.asStartElement.getName.toString match {
        case "item" =>
          ??? create new instance of some Item object?
          ??? put raw data into Map[String, String]?

        case "field1" =>
          ??? currentItem.field1 = Some(reader.getElementText)
          ??? fieldsCollection("field1") = reader.getElementText

        . . . 

        (or) case field =>
            fieldsCollection(field) = reader.getElementText

      }
    }

    if (event.isEndElement) {
      event.asEndElement.getName.toString match {
        case "item" =>
           ??? Put $currentItem into mutable collection?
           ??? Parse object from Map?
        case _ =>
      }
    }

  }
} catch {
  case e: XMLStreamException => throw e
} finally {
  reader.close()
}
```

Whats the best way to parse file with fixed list of tags, but which are all optional. Fill some object (case class)? Or fill map and then parse it into object?